# Resizable content div in container

Tags: css, positioning

I try to realize the following in CSS.
A container containing a static tabs div and a content div that wil smaller when the page become smaller.
The tabs div should just stay in the same spot.

To clarify what a picture.
[image: Example]

My code now:

```
.tabs {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
width: 100%
}

.tabss {
clear: none;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}

.tabss-content {
position: relative;
left: 30%;
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tabs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.content {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>tab one</li>
    <li>tab two</li>
    <li>tab three</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  </p>
</div>
```